# Why is my React Color popup not updating?

Tags: reactjs, react-color

I am attempting to create a button which pops up a react-color `SketchPicker` component(akin to the first example listed in [react-color's "More Examples"](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#examples)). However, when I open my popup and drag the selector in `SketchPicker`, the color in the UI does not update, and the selector does not move.

I have perused my component, and I cannot find a single aspect of it in error; I have merely updated the first component in `More Examples` to utilize `useState`.

Why is this?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcolor-popup-qnhlq)

Comment: You need to have a handler for when the colour changes, and to store the current colour in state. Have a look at the example here (it's class based, but you can convert to functional): https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#api-color

Comment: Ahhh. That makes sense. I suppose I was not careful in my reading. Though I now find that the dragging aspect of the component does not work; it only updates at the end of my drag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a color prop to SketchPicker component and also add an onChange handler so whenever you move the cursor this handler triggers and it has access to selected color which you can update the state variable and pass that state variable to color prop.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ColorSelector.css";
import { SketchPicker } from "react-color";

const ColorSelector = () => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [color, setColor] = useState({
    r: "241",
    g: "112",
    b: "19",
    a: "1"
  });
  const onClickMethod = () => {
    setDisplay(!display);
  };

  const onCloseMethod = () => {
    setDisplay(false);
  };

  const onChangeMethod = (color) => {
    setColor({ ...color.rgb });
  };

  const popover = {
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: "3"
  };

  const cover = {
    position: "fixed",
    top: "0px",
    right: "0px",
    bottom: "0px",
    left: "0px"
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <a className="colorSelector" onClick={onClickMethod}>
        select color
      </a>
      {display ? (
        <div style={popover}>
          <div style={cover} onClick={onCloseMethod} />
          <SketchPicker color={color} onChange={onChangeMethod} />
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ColorSelector;
```